# Coupling Capacitor of an Antenna

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, filter, bandwidth

I have a simple question about general meaning & importance
of the coupling capacitor in following part of
a simple receiver circuit:

[image]

Is it true that the proper reason why this
coupling capacitor C2 **is** there is simply because
it should form part of the bandpass-filter
C2-L1-C1?

[image]

Or does my interpretation hardly missing the point?

Comment: C1 in the first diagram is a variable capacitor, probably used to tune to resonance.  C1 in the second diagram is not??

Comment: The antenna is likely to be too short, not matched, so it will be capacitive too. Maybe C2 is for DC isolation of the antenna, especially in valve receivers where the "chassis" may not be at earth potential?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @user10489: yes C1 is variable, I was just to lazy to mark it explicietly in my picture. So you can assume it. But the question is still the same: which function has C2 here?

Comment: I just realized this question is nearly a copy of my own question: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16372/why-does-capacitive-loose-coupling-increase-selectivity :)

Answer (score 3):

The capacitor C2 would be of a value small enough to prevent the antenna from damping the Q of the tuned circuit.

In other words, the purpose of C2 would be to improve selectivity.

Comment: so C2 should be choosen small in order to weak the coupling of the antenna?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: What I still not understand is how to precisely see how C2 effects here 
on Q of the tuned circuit in mathematical terms. Can the Q be 
given here by explicit formula in dependence of C2, C1 and L1? 
I only know how to determine Q of elemetrary parallel and serial
RLC circuit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#RLC_circuits
but don't know which explicit techniques/ strategies are generally used to calculate Q of a bit more
complicated oscillating systems like this one. Do you know where it is 
systematically explained in detail how to calculate Q in such cases

Comment: which are a bit more complicated than elementary parallel and serial
RLC circuits?

Comment: @katalaveino - Hi, I have not come across such an explanation. You may use this on-line calculator (http://www.crystal-radio.eu/entunercalc.htm) to obtain corresponding values of the coupling capacitor for various values of Q, in order to understand its functioning.

Comment: As I wrote above, I had the same question here: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16372/why-does-capacitive-loose-coupling-increase-selectivity
I never came a across any mathematical explanation. :/ I'm also still looking for answers.